# fetch an object from array of object from express js server and send it to react frontend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, rest

I have created a list of data in mongodb. There are different category and each category, there are an array of objects of products. I want to seach individual all products in all categories with a certain key like 'email', 'name' etc but i can't do that properly.[screenshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjkmC.png)

I am trying to fetch data from all category in products array with a specific key like "email" or other key. I want to do it in react and express js but i don't know how can i do that with CURD operation.

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you